# compare two differnt arrays and output with zero at different record in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have two different arrays like below,

month array

```
0   :November
1   :October
2   :September
3   :August
4   :July
5   :June
```

data array

```
0   {
   profit   :4045
   month    :June
}
1   {
   profit   :1161
   month    :August
}
2   {
   profit   :730
   month    :October
}
3   {
   profit   :1700
   month    :November
}
```

I need to compare these two arrays and make new array with `profit` as `0`. Finally I want to get below array.

```
0   {
   profit   :4045
   month    :June
}
1   {
   profit   :0
   month    :July
}
2   {
   profit   :730
   month    :August
}
3   {
   profit   :0
   month    :September
}
4   {
   profit   :1700
   month    :October
}
5   {
   profit   :1700
   month    :November
}
```

I have tried below code, But it's not working

```
foreach ($month as $key => $value) {
  if (array_key_exists($key, $data->month) {
    $month[$key] = $data[$key];
  } else {
    $month[$key] = 0;
  }
}
```

Ho can i make this array using `month` and `data` array?

Comment: Your question shows [no attempt](//idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) of solving the problem. If you have made an attempt, you should edit our question to detail exactly what you did, researched for, and point to any links that were helpful but that did not answer your question. If you’ve tried to code a solution, that should be added in an edit. Your attempts should be turned into a [MCVE](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it is clear to read and understand. Also read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foreach` loops should do it

```
$month = array('November', 'October', 'September', 'August', 'July', 'June');
$data = array(
        array('profit' => 4045, 'month' => 'June'),
        array('profit' => 1161, 'month' => 'August'),
        array('profit' => 730, 'month' => 'October'),
        array('profit' => 1700, 'month' => 'November')
    );

// output and temp arrays
$output = [];
$temp = [];

// Loop thru each data and set month as key, profit as value
foreach ($data as $value) {
    $temp[$value['month']] = $value['profit'];
}

// Reverse month array
$month = array_reverse($month, true);

// Loop thru each month, check if month exist on temp, if not profit stays 0
foreach ($month as $value) {
    $profit = 0;
    if (array_key_exists($value, $temp)) {
        $profit = $temp[$value];
    }
    $output[] = array('profit' => $profit, 'month' => $value);
}

// Output
echo '<pre>';
print_r($output);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working. you saved my life :)